# Select rows where no record exists for past 100 years

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sorry the title isn't very good but I didn't know how to describe my problem properly

I'm trying to get a table with city names that had a disaster at least 100 years from now and since that disaster there weren't any more disaster in this city at least 100 years

so my code works but when there is a city with only one disaster in my Disaster table the city wont appear(even if he was in 1800 for example)

```
select D1.cname,D1.etype,D1.dyear
from disaster as D1 , disaster as D2
where(D1.dyear<=(date_part('year',current_date)-100)) and((D2.cname=D1.cname)and ((D2.dyear>(D1.dyear+100))))                                                                                     
group by D1.cname,D1.dyear
```

this is my data base

[image]

and this is what I'm getting from my query

[image]

im missing the cities "Tsfat" and "Kagoshima"

Im looking for your help Thanks!

with the help of @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin after the join but still dont display cities with only one disaster 
[image]

Comment: please provide your sample output in table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select D1.cname,D2.dtype,D1.dyear
from 
(
  select cname, min(dyear) as dyear
  from disaster
  where dyear<=(date_part('year',current_date)-100)
  and not exists (
    select * from disaster D3 
    where D3.cname = disaster.cname 
    and D3.dyear > disaster.dyear 
    and D3.dyear < disaster.dyear+100
  )
  group by cname
) D1
join disaster D2 on D1.cname = D2.cname and D2.dyear = D1.dyear
```

It shows only the last disaster of those cities where no disaster has happened within 100 years from that last disaster

Comment: Great just tried it and now it shows the cities that had only one disaster!

but.... we lost the check if after the disaster the city had not disaster in at least 100 years

so now for ex if Naples had 2 disasters one in 1906 and one in 1910 it still shows 1906( i changed the max to min)

Comment: @dor you're right, there was a mistake in my query - I fixed it in my post.

Comment: Great that works ty very much for your help and for everyone who tried!

Answer (score 0):

use explicit join rather comma separated table name which make cross join between two tables

```
select distinct D1.cname,D1.etype,D1.dyear
from disaster as D1  join disaster as D2
on (D1.dyear<=(date_part('year',current_date)-100)) and((D2.cname=D1.cname)and ((D2.dyear>(D1.dyear+100))))
```

I removed group by as i have not seen any aggregation

Comment: ok now its back to normal but still dosent display cities that had only one Disaster (the table look like the one that i posted Only Naples and Pasto)

Comment: @dor could you please tell me your expected output?

Comment: yes i would like to see cities that only one disaster too|
right now we are checking only cities with two disaster and more

and missing cities with one only

ty very much for your help!

Comment: @dor add your result set from your sample data you post on question

Comment: @dor add your expected output not  my query output

Comment: oh

my expected output will be this table with two more rows  cities "Tsfat" and "Kagoshima"

because they had a Disaster in at least last 100 years and didnt have anymore disasters at all

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are a more natural way to express this logic:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             lag(dyear) over (partition by cname order by dyear) as prev_dyear
      from disaster d
     ) d
where dyear >= date_part('year', current_date) - 100 and
      (prev_dyear is null or prev_dyear < dyear - 100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

but it didnt work for me im getting a table with Hilo and Naples with the years 2015 and 2012...

Comment: @dor . . . Based on your description, Hilo and Naples *should* be selected.  They have had a disaster in the last 100 years and not in the 100 years before that.

Comment: oh sorry buddy maybe i didnt make it clear enough not...

i need to show a table with cname etype and dyear
of a disaster that happened at least 100 years before this year(2018) and since the date of that disaster there werent anymore disaster in that city at least 100 years from the disaster date

is it better?

Comment: @dor . . . In your data, Naples has two disasters, one in 2012 and one in 1906.  1906 is more than 100 years before 2012.